# Nosetest hangs on json.loads

Tags: python, json, nose

I wanted to refine my testing code a bit, but got stuck all weekend long.
I use nosetest and have a function to create requests_mock, where I read data from local files.
https://github.com/peshay/tpm/blob/testrefine/tests/test_tpm.py
The issue is here with line 35, my nosetest call hangs on this and I have no idea what’s the issue and how to chase it. 
I tried to put this particular relevant code in an own test file, but there it works.
As soon as I remove the json.loads nosetests run. I also tried some different ways to read the data from the file twice, or with data_file.seek(0), but it also hangs on this call.
Can someone give me a hint what could be wrong here?

Comment: Are you certain the contents of the JSON file is valid? You are only catching `ValueError` which will not catch any any exception thrown by `json.loads`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not with json.loads, it was the following while loop.

```
while True:
    if data_len > item_limit and isinstance(data,list):
```

In this loop data_len should have been changed, but never was, so it never came to it's break point.